# How to debug inetd server on rooted Android phone?

Tags: linux, ssh, busybox

I would like to run an `inetd` server on my rooted phone to accept incoming connections and launch an application in response.  I've installed BusyBox since it includes `inetd` and I created a file `/etc/inetd.conf/myApp` with the contents:

```
service myApp
{
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    user = root
    server = /system/app/com.mydomain.myApp-33.apk
    port = 2345
    disable = no
}
```

I then ran this command from the adb shell:

```
shell@jfltevzw:/ $ su
root@jfltevzw:/ # busybox inetd -q 2345 /etc/xinetd.d/myApp
```

I then tried to test by using telnet from my Macintosh:

```
bash-3.2$ telnet 192.168.1.29 2345
Trying 192.168.1.29...
Connected to android-1c7bde8dccfe2a27.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried other not-configured ports (e.g. 2346) and get the same result, so it is failing at a very basic level and not getting very far at all.

How can I see any log files to figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mix up inetd and xinetd configuration and paths - use a config for one or the other. You may also want to consider to specify the service as type "unlisted" to avoid the need of it being added to /etc/services - as you didn't mention you did add your service, I suppose you didn't.

Comment: Correct, service is not registered for its ports.  Please elaborate on what you mean by mixing up inetd and xinetd configuration and paths - use a config for one or the other.